# Syncfusion metro form: white line below title bar

Tags: winforms, syncfusion

I have just started using the syncfusion control suit. The issue I am facing is,
when I use the metro form and change the title bar background color and the form background color to any color other than white, it shows a white line just below the title bar. Its a bad UI experience. Whereas all the syncfusion examples on their site don't show any such line under the title bar. Please see the attached screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change this by BottomBorderColor property of Form.[image]

Regards,
Susmitha S

Comment: Thanks @Susmitha, that solved the issue, now even though the form border is of the type sizable, i am not able to resize the form from the four sizes. The grip doesn't appear on the bottom right corner either which should appear ideally. Kindly suggest a solution.

Comment: Hi,

We were able to resize the SfForm from all four sides.

Video link: https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/276641/ze/ResizetheSfFormFromFourSides1380326693

Sample link: https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/276641/ze/SfFormDemo1901335350

If we misunderstood anything, please modify the above sample based on your requirement and get back to us with following details, 
 
• Syncfusion updated version.
• Issue reproducing video (If possible).
 
It will be helpful for us to investigate further. 

Regards,
Susmitha S